# Can a Force choke be countered?

Tags: star-wars

Like Darth Vader, Asajj Ventress was often seen choking people, many times Jedi like Anakin and Obi-Wan.  Is it possible for Force-users or non-Force-users to counter or defend against a Force choke without distracting the attacker or using ysalamiri?

Comment: Force judo-chop?

Comment: In theory you should be able to counter Force choke. Force choke is just an aspect of telekinesis focused on the throat, and there are many examples of telekinesis being blocked, such as the awful Force-push palm-wrestling contest between Anakin and Obi-wan on Mustafar. As with all Force powers it depends on potential, training, aptitude and the context (concentration, and so on).

Comment: isnt there a scene with darth mauls brother where he counters dookus force choke?

Answer (score 4):

Well a Force Choke does not really disable any of the victims own force powers, nor does it prevent a non-force user from retaliating while being choked. So a choke could be countered by another force user using their own force powers (ex. A large force wave to knock back the choker) or even by a non-force user using conventional weapons (A blaster could still be blocked, But I'm thinking explosives like Jace Malcolm did against darth malgus while locked in combat, though not a force choke).

If you are ok with a non-canon reference, in numerous video games, a choke can be countered with a force push.

So going on the fact a force choke only strangles and does not prevent retaliation, a victim could theoretically retaliate.